# Strange results when finding a maximum subject to constraints?

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization

I'm using 11.1.1, and I tried running the following:

```
f[x_,y_]=Sin[x+y]/(1+x^2+y^2)
NMaximize[{f[x,y],y==x},{x,y}]
>>>{0.0894384, {x -> -2.15804, y -> -2.15804}}
```

However, without the constraint:

```
NMaximize[f[x,y],{x,y}]
>>>{0.561083, {x -> 0.49257, y -> 0.49257}}
```

x is equal to y, so this max satisfies the constraints. Even weirder:

```
NMinimize[{f[x, y], x == y}, {x, y}]
>>>{-0.561083, {x -> -0.49257, y -> -0.49257}}
```

What's happening here? I'm wondering if it possibly has to do with handling floating point but I'm not sure.

Some further investigating:

I extracted the results and I showed all digits:

It said:

```
 x->0.4925702373142175
 y->0.4925702373142176
```

Is it possible there's something going on with this?

Answer (score 8):

The constrained version seems to be getting trapped in local extrema too easily. Switch to a different method, e.g.

```
NMaximize[{f[x, y], y == x}, {x, y}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

or fiddle with the random number generator:

```
NMaximize[{f[x, y], y == x}, {x, y}, Method -> {Automatic, "RandomSeed" -> 42}]
```

or try any of a number of other settings as detailed in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html).

Comment: That fixed it - thanks! Why was it able to find the min but not the max using the same method?

Comment: Like I said, it's possible that the default Nelder-Mead method gave up too quickly after getting stuck in a literal rut. Optimization can be a tricky business.

Answer (score 0):

[`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) does not guarantee a global maximum for all cases. From the documentation for `NMaximize`: "If `f` and `cons` are linear, `NMaximize` can always find global maxima, over both real and integer values.  Otherwise, `NMaximize` may sometimes find only a local maximum."

```
f[x_, y_] = Sin[x + y]/(1 + x^2 + y^2);

NMaximize[{f[x, y], y == x}, {x, y}]

(* {0.0894384, {x -> -2.15804, y -> -2.15804}} *)

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Add the additional constraint that `x` (and hence `y`) is positive)

```
NMaximize[{f[x, y], y == x, x > 0}, {x, y}]

(* {0.561083, {x -> 0.49257, y -> 0.49257}} *)
```

This is the same as the unconstrained solution.

```
NMaximize[f[x, y], {x, y}]

(* {0.561083, {x -> 0.49257, y -> 0.49257}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, embed the constraint

```
NMaximize[f[x, x], x]

(* {0.561083, {x -> 0.49257}} *)
```